# StackExchange.Redis async call hangs

Tags: c#, async-await, stackexchange.redis

Trying to figure out why this code hangs. I can remove any one of the 3 lines at the bottom of the test and it won't hang, but all 3 together makes it hang. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
[Fact]
public async Task CanAddValuesInParallel() {
    var muxer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
    var db = muxer.GetDatabase();

    await AddAsync(db, "test", "1");
    await db.KeyDeleteAsync("test");

    Task.Run(() => AddAsync(db, "test", "1")).Wait();
}

public async Task<bool> AddAsync(IDatabase db, string key, string value) {
    return await db.StringSetAsync(key, value, null, When.NotExists);
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `Task.Run` and why `Wait()`?

Comment: I think problem in `Task.Run(() => AddAsync(db, "test", "1")).Wait();`. Here you have deadlock.

Comment: This is the simplified version of my code. Trying to break it down to be as simplified as possible. I am trying to understand what is going on.

Comment: Apparently I am running into this issue: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/88

Comment: @EricJ.Smith: xUnit has a bad habit of providing a `SynchronizationContext` for all its test methods. This can cause a number of problems when mixing synchronous and asynchronous code. I suspect you're seeing some combination of problems I describe in two blog posts [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary This happens in nunit as well.

Comment: @BlakeNiemyjski: For `async Task` unit test methods, or just `async void` ones?

Comment: I haven't tried async void only async Task because I've had issues with async void unit tests :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds to me like a sync-context deadlock from mixing `Wait` and `await`. Which is why you **never do that** - (switching into "Gilbert and Sullivan"): *[well, hardly ever!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.M.S._Pinafore)*

If it helps, I *suspect* that removing the `await` in the `Wait` subtree will fix it - which should be trivial since that tree can be replaced with a trivial pass-thru:

```
public Task<bool> AddAsync(IDatabase db, string key, string value) {
    return db.StringSetAsync(key, value, null, When.NotExists);
}
```

The important point here is that SE.Redis bypasses sync-context internally (normal for library code), so it shouldn't have the deadlock.

But ultimately: mixing `Wait` and `await` is not a good idea. In addition to deadlocks, this is "sync over async" - an anti-pattern.