# Deadlock when accessing StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, asynchronous, deadlock, stackexchange.redis

I'm running into a deadlock situation when calling [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis).

I don't know exactly what is going on, which is very frustrating, and I would appreciate any input that could help resolve or workaround this problem.

---

> **In case you have this problem too and don't want to read all this;**
>   I suggest that you'll try setting `PreserveAsyncOrder` to `false`.
>
> ```
> ConnectionMultiplexer connection = ...;
> connection.PreserveAsyncOrder = false;
> ```
>
> Doing so will probably resolve the kind of deadlock that this Q&A is about and could also improve performance.

---

#### Our setup

- The code is run as either a Console application or as an Azure Worker Role.
- It exposes a REST api using [HttpMessageHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler(v=vs.118).aspx) so the entry point is async.
- Some parts of the code have thread affinity (is owned by, and must be run by, a single thread).
- Some parts of the code is async-only.
- We are doing the [*sync-over-async*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx) and [*async-over-sync*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) anti-patterns. (mixing `await` and `Wait()`/`Result`).
- We're only using async methods when accessing Redis.
- We're using StackExchange.Redis 1.0.450 for .NET 4.5.

#### Deadlock

When the application/service is started it runs normally for a while then all of a sudden (almost) all incoming requests stop functioning, they never produce a response. All those requests are deadlocked waiting for a call to Redis to complete.

Interestingly, once the deadlock occur, any call to Redis will hang but only if those calls are made from an incoming API request, which are run on the thread pool.

We are also making calls to Redis from low priority background threads, and these calls continue to function even after the deadlock occurred.

<strike>*It seems as if a deadlock will only occur when calling into Redis on a thread pool thread.*</strike> I no longer think this is due to the fact that those calls are made on a thread pool thread. Rather, it seems like any async Redis call **without continuation, or with a *sync safe* continuation,** will continue to work even after the deadlock situation has occurred. (See *What I think happens* below)

#### Related

- [StackExchange.Redis Deadlocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235124/stackexchange-redis-deadlocking)

  Deadlock caused by mixing `await` and `Task.Result` (sync-over-async, like we do). But our code is run without synchronization context so that doesn't apply here, right?
- [How to safely mix sync and async code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296325/how-to-safely-mix-sync-and-async-code)

  Yes, we shouldn't be doing that. But we do, and we'll have to continue doing so for a while. Lots of code that needs to be migrated into the async world.

  Again, we don't have a synchronization context, so this should not be causing deadlocks, right?

  Setting `ConfigureAwait(false)` before any `await` has no effect on this.
- [Timeout exception after async commands and Task.WhenAny awaits in StackExchange.Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567566/timeout-exception-after-async-commands-and-task-whenany-awaits-in-stackexchange)

  This is the thread hijacking problem. What's the current situation on this? Could this be the problem here?
- [StackExchange.Redis async call hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258984/stackexchange-redis-async-call-hangs/)

  From Marc's answer:

  > ...mixing Wait and await is not a good idea. In addition to deadlocks, this is "sync over async" - an anti-pattern.

  But he also says:

  > SE.Redis bypasses sync-context internally (normal for library code), so it shouldn't have the deadlock

  So, from my understanding StackExchange.Redis should be agnostic to whether we're using the *sync-over-async* anti-pattern. It's just not recommended as it could be the cause of deadlocks in **other** code.

  In this case, however, as far as I can tell, the deadlock is really inside StackExchange.Redis. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

#### Debug findings

I've found that the deadlock seems to have its source in `ProcessAsyncCompletionQueue` on [line 124 of `CompletionManager.cs`](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/CompletionManager.cs#L124).

Snippet of that code:

```
while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref activeAsyncWorkerThread, currentThread, 0) != 0)
{
    // if we don't win the lock, check whether there is still work; if there is we
    // need to retry to prevent a nasty race condition
    lock(asyncCompletionQueue)
    {
        if (asyncCompletionQueue.Count == 0) return; // another thread drained it; can exit
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1);
}
```

I've found that during the deadlock; `activeAsyncWorkerThread` is one of our threads that is waiting for a Redis call to complete. (*our thread* = a thread pool thread running *our code*). So the loop above is deemed to continue forever.

Without knowing the details, this sure feels wrong; StackExchange.Redis is waiting for a thread that it thinks is the *active async worker thread* while it is in fact a thread that is quite the opposite of that.

I wonder if this is due to the *thread hijacking problem* (which I don't fully understand)?

#### What to do?

The main two question I'm trying to figure out:

1. Could mixing `await` and `Wait()`/`Result` be the cause of deadlocks even when running without synchronization context?
2. Are we running into a bug/limitation in StackExchange.Redis?

#### A possible fix?

From my debug findings it seems as the problem is that:

```
next.TryComplete(true);
```

...on [line 162 in `CompletionManager.cs`](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/CompletionManager.cs#L162) could under some circumstances let the current thread (which is the *active async worker thread*) wander off and start processing other code, possibly causing a deadlock.

Without knowing the details and just thinking about this "fact", then it would seem logical to temporarily release the *active async worker thread* during the `TryComplete` invocation.

I guess that something like this could work:

```
// release the "active thread lock" while invoking the completion action
Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref activeAsyncWorkerThread, 0, currentThread);

try
{
    next.TryComplete(true);
    Interlocked.Increment(ref completedAsync);
}
finally
{
    // try to re-take the "active thread lock" again
    if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref activeAsyncWorkerThread, currentThread, 0) != 0)
    {
        break; // someone else took over
    }
}
```

I guess my best hope is that [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) would read this and provide some feedback :-)

#### No synchronization context = The default synchronization context

I've written above that our code does not use a [synchronization context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx). This is only partially true: The code is run as either a Console application or as an Azure Worker Role. In these environments [`SynchronizationContext.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx) is `null`, which is why I wrote that we're running *without* synchronization context.

However, after reading [*It's All About the SynchronizationContext*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/gg598924.aspx) I've learned that this is not really the case:

> By convention, if a thread’s current SynchronizationContext is null, then it implicitly has a default SynchronizationContext.

The default synchronization context should not be the cause of deadlocks though, as UI-based (WinForms, WPF) synchronization context could - because it does not imply thread affinity.

#### What I think happens

When a message is completed its completion source is checked for whether it is considered *sync safe*. If it is, the completion action is executed inline and everything is fine.

If it is not, the idea is to execute the completion action on a newly allocated thread pool thread. This too works just fine when `ConnectionMultiplexer.PreserveAsyncOrder` is `false`.

However, when `ConnectionMultiplexer.PreserveAsyncOrder` is `true` (the default value), then those thread pool threads will serialize their work using a *completion queue* and by ensuring that at most one of them is the *active async worker thread* at any time.

When a thread becomes the *active async worker thread* it will continue to be that until it have drained the *completion queue*.

The problem is that the completion action is *not sync safe* (from above), still it is executed on a thread that **must not be blocked** as that will prevent other *non sync safe* messages from being completed.

Notice that other messages that are being completed with a completion action that *is sync safe* will continue to work just fine, even though the *active async worker thread* is blocked.

My suggested "fix" (above) would not cause a deadlock in this way, it would however mess with the notion of *preserving async completion order*.

So maybe the conclusion to make here is that **it is not safe to mix `await` with `Result`/`Wait()` when `PreserveAsyncOrder` is `true`**, no matter whether we are running without synchronization context?

(*At least until we can use .NET 4.6 and the new [`TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx), I suppose*)

Comment: It is very hard to form an opinion here, because you aren't showing any of the code that actually calls SE.Redis or does any waiting / awaiting - which is the critical code... can you show you are calling it?

Comment: @MarcGravell: I can show you any code, although not in its entirety. However, the problem is that I don't know which code is the interesting part here. Please see my recent edit (at the end), I think the problem is generic and due to a *non sync safe* completion action being executed by the *active async worker thread* which will cause a deadlock when blocked.

Comment: Although not an answer what a well written question.

Comment: The sync-over async deadlock is also caused in asp.net applications when the synchronization context that called the async method is the one that it tries to return to , even if it is from a  background thread.

Comment: I'm seeing this same scenario in some specific case, reproducable in my local dev environment. Not sure what triggers this, but it's the exact same deadlock symptom -- qs says stuff is sent, in says stuff is received, but it hangs. This is with entirely sync calls to SE Redis, no async at all. Setting PreserveAsyncOrder fixes this, but that seems sort of magicky. @MarcGravell any ideas on this?

Comment: How can a deadlock be identified? Does the error message mention a deadlock or does the client get a timeout error?

Comment: @Keith you won't get an error message when there is a deadlock. All code paths trying to enter the critical section that is deadlocked will just never complete. If things stop responding, seemingly forever, then you've might run into a deadlock situation.

Comment: `PreserveAsyncOrder` is no longer supported (Obsolete), has this been addressed in the core lib I wonder?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

These are the workarounds I've found to this deadlock problem:

#### Workaround #1

By default StackExchange.Redis will ensure that commands are completed in the same order that result messages are received. This could cause a deadlock as described in this question.

Disable that behavior by setting `PreserveAsyncOrder` to `false`.

```
ConnectionMultiplexer connection = ...;
connection.PreserveAsyncOrder = false;
```

This will avoid deadlocks and could also [improve performance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/best-practices-caching/).

I encourage anyone that run into to deadlock problems to try this workaround, since it's so clean and simple.

You'll loose the guarantee that async continuations are invoked in the same order as the underlying Redis operations are completed. However, I don't really see why that is something you would rely on.

---

#### Workaround #2

The deadlock occur when the *active async worker thread* in StackExchange.Redis completes a command and when the completion task is executed inline.

One can prevent a task from being executed inline by using a custom [`TaskScheduler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(v=vs.110).aspx) and ensure that [`TryExecuteTaskInline`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449178(v=vs.110).aspx) returns `false`.

```
public class MyScheduler : TaskScheduler
{
    public override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        return false; // Never allow inlining.
    }

    // TODO: Rest of TaskScheduler implementation goes here...
}
```

Implementing a good task scheduler may be a complex task. There are, however, existing implementations in the [ParallelExtensionExtras library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx) ([NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSFT.ParallelExtensionsExtras/)) that you can use or draw inspiration from.

If your task scheduler would use its own threads (not from the thread pool), then it might be a good idea to allow inlining unless the current thread is from the thread pool. This will work because the *active async worker thread* in StackExchange.Redis is always a thread pool thread.

```
public override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
{
    // Don't allow inlining on a thread pool thread.
    return !Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread && this.TryExecuteTask(task);
}
```

Another idea would be to attach your scheduler to all of its threads, using [thread-local storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private static ThreadLocal<TaskScheduler> __attachedScheduler 
                   = new ThreadLocal<TaskScheduler>();
```

Ensure that this field is assigned when the thread starts running and cleared as it completes:

```
private void ThreadProc()
{
    // Attach scheduler to thread
    __attachedScheduler.Value = this;

    try
    {
        // TODO: Actual thread proc goes here...
    }
    finally
    {
        // Detach scheduler from thread
        __attachedScheduler.Value = null;
    }
}
```

Then you can allow inlining of tasks as long as its done on a thread that is "owned" by the custom scheduler:

```
public override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
{
    // Allow inlining on our own threads.
    return __attachedScheduler.Value == this && this.TryExecuteTask(task);
}
```

Comment: Note: As of **Release 2.0.495** `PreserveAsyncOrder` has been deprecated.

Comment: @tehmas any suggestions on where the new flag is inside `ConnectionMultiplexer` after `PreserveAsyncOrder` becomes deprecated? Or if there is flag somewhere else within `StackExchange.Redis`?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing a lot based on the detailed information above and not knowing the source code you have in place. It sounds like you may be hitting some internal, and configurable, limits in .Net. You shouldn't be hitting those, so my guess is that you are not disposing of objects since they are floating between threads which won't allow you to use a using statement to cleanly handle their object lifetimes.

This details the limitations on HTTP requests. Similar to the old WCF issue when you didn't dispose of the connection and then all WCF connections would fail.

[Max number of concurrent HttpWebRequests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361771/max-number-of-concurrent-httpwebrequests)

This is more of a debugging aid, since I doubt you really are using all the TCP ports, but good info on how to find how many open ports you have and to where.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610(v=bts.20).aspx

Comment: Thank you. But this problem is not caused by running out of TCP ports or HTTP connections.